# C <sys/stat.h> Find file type

Tags: c, file, types, ls

I create my own ls command for a project and I use the "st_mode" variable to find the files permissions but I don't use the macros.

Ex:
st_mode = 16877

I convert it in octal base:

st_mode = 40755

I keep the three last characters and I get my permissions.

But when I try to find the file's type, I try to use the two first characters but they don't really help me...
So I would like to know if I can use the two first characters to find the file's type (Link, folder,...). And if I can't, what I should use to find the file's type

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can use both method with predefined macros as below, open the man page of stat() system call, it says

```
S_IFMT     0170000   bit mask for the file type bit fields
```

So do `&` of `st_mode` and `S_IFMT`, you will get file type

```
                struct stat v;
                stat(file,&v);  
                switch (v.st_mode & S_IFMT) // type of file
                {

                        case S_IFBLK:  printf("b");                 break;
                        case S_IFCHR:  printf("c");                 break;
                        case S_IFDIR:  printf("d");                 break;
                        case S_IFIFO:  printf("p");                 break;
                        case S_IFLNK:  printf("l");                 break;
                        case S_IFREG:  printf("-");                 break;
                        case S_IFSOCK: printf("s");                 break;
                        default:       printf("unknown?");          break;
                }
```

If you don't want to use macros then first find out `st_mode` value of each type of `files` & then write the logic. for e.g `st_mode` value of `regular file` is `10664`, last 3 digits(664) for `permission`, write the binary of 10664 you will come to know that `15th` bit is set so do `st.mode >> 15` . Similarly find the st_mode value of different types of file & analyse.

```
if( ( v.st_mode >> 15 & 1) && ( v.st_mode >> 14 & 1) ) 
                printf("Socket File\n"); 
        else if( ( v.st_mode >> 15 & 1) && ( v.st_mode >> 13 & 1) )
                printf("Symbolic Link File\n");
        else if( v.st_mode >> 15 & 1) 
                printf("Regular File\n");
        else if((v.st_mode >> 14 & 1) && (v.st_mode >> 13 & 1) )
                printf("Block Dev File\n");
        else if(v.st_mode >> 14 & 1) 
                printf("Directory File\n");
        else if(v.st_mode >> 13 & 1)
                printf("Char Dev File\n");
        else if(v.st_mode >> 12 & 1)
                printf("FIFO/PIPE File\n");
```

I hope it help's .

Answer (score 1):

Per the [POSIX <sys/stat.h> documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html#tag_13_62):

> The following macros shall be provided to test whether a file is of
>   the specified type. The value m supplied to the macros is the value of
>   st_mode from a stat structure. The macro shall evaluate to a non-zero
>   value if the test is true; 0 if the test is false.
>
> ```
> S_ISBLK(m)
>     Test for a block special file.
> S_ISCHR(m)
>     Test for a character special file.
> S_ISDIR(m)
>     Test for a directory.
> S_ISFIFO(m)
>     Test for a pipe or FIFO special file.
> S_ISREG(m)
>     Test for a regular file.
> S_ISLNK(m)
>     Test for a symbolic link.
> S_ISSOCK(m)
>     Test for a socket.
> ```

Comment: Yes but if i check with macros i will need to check each cases

Comment: @M4gie *Yes but if i check with macros i will need to check each cases* You have to check all the cases you're interested in anyway, with or without macros.